# WPF ListBox IsEditable = True behavior?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a 'ListBox' that I am currently using to fill up items.

However, I need the behavior that is similiar to how a combobox behaves as if its 'IsEditable '= "True" .

that is the combox filters the items based on what I enter into the text field...

I want similiar behavior in the ListBox.

And I cannot make use of a ComboBox in this case .. I need to manipulate the listbox to behave like that.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. There's no built-in mode like there is for a ComboBox (since by default a ListBox has no text-entry capacity - it just displays items), but you can achieve the same behavior by binding the ListBox to a `CollectionView` and using the view's filtering abilities.

[This blog post](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=32) gives an example (with source) for how that's done.

**Update:** That whole domain seems to be offline, here's that post [on the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121211183021/http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=32).